# Fan-non fiction market appeal

Tags: publishing, structure, marketing

I found the discussion of flat vs round characters in the answer to this post pretty interesting: [Example of a fictional story without any characters (the story being 1000+ words)](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/example-of-a-fictional-story-without-any-characters-the-story-being-1000-words). Borrowing this analytical framework, that got me weighing the possibility of a story based on entirely 'flat characters.' Structure might entail something like:

- characters come in, and exit story never reappearing
- Presumably, there would be some kind of subject to anchor things (inanimate object/place)
- Some events would be boring, other events might read as climaxes based on conventional analysis (though I would not treat them as climaxes, no build up, no foreshadowing, no afterthought)

### A little something I whipped up to demonstrate

> A tyrannosaurus ravaged through the gore of its most recent kill. The
> Mesozoic sun glimmered brightly in the sky as the eviscerated corpse
> dried up in matter of hours. In the distance the shriek of a
> brachiosaurus ripped through the oxygen-dense air. It's painful demise
> ended slowly between the jaws of a vicious predator moments before the
> colossal impact of its body pummeled the earth.

### Thoughts

And on and on it would go, with only modest transitions or even hard cuts between events. Here is my motivation:

- I want to pioneer or develop a style "fan non-fiction" where we make things up using what modern science suggests would be plausible. So its definitely not non-fiction in the strictest sense, but I think it would be a simplification to label it as "fantasy."
- The point is to avoid using conventional plot devices to show mother nature as she truly is, indifferent. Things happen, or maybe nothing happens, time just rolls on.
- The target publication length would be about 500 pages long.
- To compensate for the potential boredom that would set in from not being able to relate to any of the characters and/or lack of central plot, I would try to create value in descriptive, engaging, imagery-intensive sentences that are scientifically accurate.
- Actually, it wouldn't really matter where you started reading the book, since it's the piece is just an aggregate of discrete events, but after reading all 500 pages, I would suspect someone would actually feel like they have witnessed the period of the Mesozoic for themselves.

### Question

What are some likely concerns publishers would have, and how might I prepare to address them without compromising the spirit of my non-standard publication idea?

Comment: So, just "fiction"?  Possibly "historical fiction", depending on how intertwined it is with significant historical events, or just a fictional documentary (à la [Walking with Dinosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walking_with_Dinosaurs)) .  The "fan" in "fan-fiction" doesn't stand for "fantasy".

Comment: Let's summarize - you would write about the nature (ancient or not), there will be no sentient characters and no plot?